# Convert key and certificate

Tags: macos, ssl-certificate, private-key

I am using Mac OS X. I have the following files

- key.rtf
- cert.rtf

These files are PEM encoded and contain the key and the certificate in text form (`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`).

How can I:

1. decrypt the private key with the passphrase I used to encrypt it and get it back in text form?
2. get both files in PEM format as text (!) back?

The PEM encoding makes problems - if the files are stored as .key, .cert or anything like this, it works properly. But I need the text.

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with this command: `openssl rsa -in cert.pem -out server.key` (I converted the files to a cert.pem file before).